# How to modify plugins Dart code Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a Flutter app, and it uses [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) plugin. I want to add new functionalities to the plugin by modifying the source code. How do I find the actual source code of the plugin in my project after installing it through Flutter?

**How plugin is added in Flutter**

The dependency for `map_view` plugin is added to `pubspec.yaml` as below, then running `flutter packages get` will add it to the project. 
           dev_dependecies:
              map_view:

Answer (score 94):

Here is step by step of how to modify plugin locally, my plugin named: `flutter_abc-0.4.1`

1. Right click on package/plugin's import file name, choose Reveal in Finder
   Or hold CMD + Click on that file name to go to that file, then Right click anywhere in the file and choose "Reveal in Finder".

Normally it's located at `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_abc-0.4.1`

2. Copy whole package folder to your app folder

For easy hijacking files, just copy all to your app folder (same level with `pubspec.yaml`, not in the `lib` folder), then renaming version:

For example: `flutter_abc-0.4.1-hijacking`

Now you can modify whatever you want to fix bug locally.

3. Modify **pubspec.yaml** to point to local package

Open your project **pubspec.yaml**
Change path of dependencies to, for example:

`flutter_abc: path: ./flutter_abcd-0.4.1-hijacking/`

Comment: One can always refer to official [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages) and use local directory or Git repository.

Comment: I was trying to do the same way but some how its not working for iOS build. GeneratedPluginRegistrant in ios doesn't contain any entry for the plugin that I include with `path:` and I consistently get the error on run `MissingPluginException` I tried flutter clean, upgrade, pod file clean update but nothing worked. Does anybody has any suggestion for this?

Comment: Probably you are not using relative path, please check your pod config or anywhere with path related.

Comment: What if I directly change the code there instead of copying? Will it be permanent?

Comment: No, when you run `flutter pub get`, it will download and replace your changes.

Comment: It is worth noting that you should delete example folders since they contain internal `import` statements that will make the compiler complain about unreachable URI's. [darturi_does_not_exist](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#uri_does_not_exist)

Comment: This does not work for internal packages. For instance, I want to modify WebSocket in dart:io (actually dart:_http) but cannot copy clearly... It has so many internal dependencies...

Answer (score 28):

The most elegant way is to [fork a repo](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), do all changes you need and commit them to your fork of the repo. After that you just need to [add forked repo from git](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) as a dependency in `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

With the git reposity of the desired plugin [here](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view)

Clone it.

Make your modification

Submit a pull request.

And done

Comment: How can I test it locally before submitting a pull request? I think running `flutter packages get` will get the published plugin.

Comment: You can specify a local path for your plugin instead of a version number.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use packages by importing them in the files where we need them.
To modify a plugin, you need to Ctrl + click on the import line (for e.g. import 'package:dio/dio.dart';) ctrl + clicking on this line will open the source code for this plugin. You can edit the code there. 
Remember, the change won't be permanent and if you push your code to git and then clone it later, the changes you've done will be reverted to the original. 
So to avoid this, you can just copy all the source code and make a separate dart file and copy and modify all the code there to play safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth stating that for quick testing / debugging, you can actually modify the code directly in your `.pub-cache`, e.g. `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-2.3.0/lib/video_player.dart`. For it to take effect, you must fully restart your app, a hot reload won't work.