# How can I center the icon with helper text in textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyway I'm able to do this or interpolate the value from a string? The helper text only takes a  String type.

Below is what I'm aiming to do.

edit: I've tried wrapping the icon with center however it just pushes the text out the field.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w82a.png)

```
 class SearchField extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Styles.formField,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              hintText: '${Icon(Icons.search)} Search',
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: Updated, also  If Interpolate the  string I just get

Icon(IconData(U+0e8B6))

Comment: Could you add some code? It would be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Updated, the image attached is what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using Flutter's provided material widgets. You probably need to create your own *custom* `TextField` widget, which you could base off of the one provided by Flutter by creating a hijacked version following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296617/how-to-modify-plugins-dart-code-flutter). Or, if you're lucky, someone has already make a package that does what you want and made it available at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).

Comment: I'll check this out and update e this with what I've found.

Comment: did you make it? @Adrianwritenow

Comment: In a sense yes, I used flappy search bar in pub.dev and modified it form there.

https://blog.smartnsoft.com/an-automatic-search-bar-in-flutter-flappy-search-bar-a470bc67fa1f

@jeremy HOFFMAN