# How do I customize a flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-packages

I've added a package to my pubspec.ymal file and got my package into the dart packages folder and I want to do some changes in the file according to my app how can I do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify plugins Dart code Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296617/how-to-modify-plugins-dart-code-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

u cant.... what u need to do is copy the Whole package code.. put it inside ur project then make changes.

Comment: is it okay to that even in production level?

Comment: yeah, but the better solution would be to fork the project and keep it seperate from your exisitng project and in pubspec import the forked package after modifying it

Comment: is it legal ? as packages are licensed !

Comment: for that i think you need to read original package Terms and Conditions