# Working with customized packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just customized a flutter package by modifying the files directly from /Users/tomcajot/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/my_customized_package_folder. Now I'd like to share my project with a coworker who will have to launch te project. How can I add this customized package to my project?

Comment: publish it to pub.dev

Comment: This is a package from pub.dev that I customized. This isn't my package. Isn't there an other way?

Comment: create a folder called packages or sth in lib and use it as other files. Also mark it as read only. See here for more info https://codewithandrea.com/videos/how-to-create-dart-packages-flutter-apps/

Comment: Thanks, but I found an other way.

Comment: please share your full steps

Comment: I created an answer with the right steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify plugins Dart code Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296617/how-to-modify-plugins-dart-code-flutter)

Comment: Thanks but I already found an other way.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add a customized package to your project:

- Copy the modified package.
- Create a new github repo.
- Add the package to the repo.
- Specify the package's new location in pubspec.yaml like this:

  ```
  my_custom_package:
    git: https://github.com/tomcajot/my_custom_package
  ```