# Can you somehow edit EnglishWords package contents, so it has different words?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

Im using a flutter tutorial, in order to learn about it, and i was wondering if i can change the words in the package to fit some theme, like food and such.

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at this link to find what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296617/how-to-modify-plugins-dart-code-flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.